# .gitignore not ignoring the files Django

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, gitignore

So I'm testing out Heroku with a dummy app called hellodjango, and pushing everything to git.

Added my .gitignore file (tell me if I'm wrong, I created a text document called django.gitignore, and the contents are 1 line, no spaces, venv*.log*.pot*.pyclocal_settings.py.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here is my directory

```
hellodjango/
    django.gitignore
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
    hellodjango/
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
        settings.py
        settings.pyc
        urls.py
        urls.pyc
        wsgi.py
        wsgi.pyc
    venv/
        Include/
        Lib/
        Scripts/
```

So I don't want to stage any .pyc files or the venv folder.

In my command line, I enter

> git init

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/Chris/hellodjango/.git/
>git add .
>git status
```

When I enter git status, all of the files in venv and .pyc are staged. Why is .gitignore not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gitignore file needs to be named only `.gitignore` without a `django` in front of the dot.

You can find more information about ignoring files and possible patterns supported in the ProGit book on the official website: [ProGit Chapter 2-2](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-2.html).

Comment: Ok, just did that. So my directory is still the same as above, but now instead of django.gitignore, I just have a file called .gitignore. In the file, I have this venv*.log*.pot*.pyclocal_settings.py. Ran git add ., and still venv and .pyc were staged. any explanation?

Comment: Separate the patterns in different lines. And the pattern for rejecting .pyc files is: `*.pyc`

Comment: Moreover - if you already added all the .pyc files via `git add .` you have to remove them from the staging area before your gitignore file will work for the staged files again. Unstaging is done via `git rm --cached <file_to_unstage>`